# QTCreator segfault after 1st run

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qt-creator

I've recently had a horrible problem with QTCreator. After the first time of running the program, **ALL** debugging instances segfault upon constructing the MainWindow object. Even if i make a blank QTwidget project and run in debug (without editing a single bloody thing), i get a segfault.

This persists after dozens of reinstalls. I have tried both the SDK as well as the IDE and library seperately. The version of the library is irrelevant, i **always** get the seg fault and its **only** on my tower. My laptops work just fine.

Does anyone have any possible solutions? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of QtCreator are you using?  What OS is on your tower?  What are the architectural/platform/tool differences between your laptop and your tower?

Comment: I apologize for not getting back sooner. I didn't get the email stating someone responded to me. I have 64  bit windows using QTCreator 2.4 with QT 4.8. The issue occured when using the C++11x build settings. They work fine on 32 bit machines but fail on 64 bit.

Comment: You have got the 64bit Qt runtime libraries installed on your tower right?  Does it work without C++11 support enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run QtCreator in admin mode in order for GDB to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more (please answer to cbamber85's comment), such issues are known to be caused by uberprotectious anti-virus solutions or other software that hooks into places where GDB would usually hook in (Vendor OS-'enhancement' tools are infamous for doing that). This is a known Problem with GDB.

You could try to disable your virus scanner or remove/unload/remove from autostart the vendor tools and try again.

If that doesn't work, the content of the debugger output log pane (Windows > Views > Debugger Log) would be interesting.